# Do I have to tell the DM which creature I am attacking before rolling the attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack

Is there something in RAW that says if I have to speak out loud who I am attacking before rolling the d20? What rule says it?

Comment: If you don't tell the DM what you're doing, are you really attacking or are you just rolling a d20 for the fun of it? What would prevent you from rolling d20s "for fun" until you get a 20 and then saying, "I rolled this 20 to attack that guy."

Comment: My question is about RAW.

Comment: I feel like this might be an X/Y problem; why are you asking? What is the problem that this question's answer is trying to resolve?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### In general, you pick a target before rolling anything

The rules for [making an attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack) state :

> 1. **Choose a target.** Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, or a location.
> 2. **Determine modifiers.** The DM determines whether the target has cover and whether you have advantage or disadvantage against the target. In addition, spells, special abilities, and other effects can apply penalties or bonuses to your attack roll.
> 3. **Resolve the attack.** You make the attack roll. On a hit, you roll damage, unless the particular attack has rules that specify otherwise. Some attacks cause special effects in addition to or instead of damage.

As you can see, picking the target is step 1, and you only make any rolls on step 3 so you do need to set the target before rolling.

Also note that for the DM to be able to do step 2, the DM needs to know which target you picked so you do have to share that information.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Additionally, the basic loop of D&D is that the player states what they want their character to do, the GM determines what rolls (if any) are required (and any modifications - advantage, etc.), the rolls are made, and the GM describes the new state of the world. An attack is just another action; the player's intent would be "hit the goblin with my sword".

Comment: @minnmass I also looked at the general [how to play](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#HowtoPlay) section which is what you are mentioning but combat does follow a more structured set of rules. It even says so in said section. Therefore I think it better to keep this short and simple, specifically about how attacks work.

Comment: @Sdjz: I agree; my intent was to point out that your - quite correct - answer was backed up by the more general case of generic action resolution. ... that is, "yes, you have to tell the GM what you're trying to do before you can roll to see if you were successful".